# If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ is a uniformly continuous function then its absolutely continuous?

Tags: integration, derivatives, continuity, uniform-continuity

If $f:[a,b]\rightarrow R$ is a uniformly continuous function

then is it true that $f$ is always absolutely continuous?

Comment: 1). You ask about functions defined on a compact, so uniform continuity is equivalent to continuity. 2). [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_continuity#Examples) (or most likely any textbook introducing the concept of absolute continuity) will give you at least one example of a function that is continuous (on a compact) yet not absolutely continuous (on that compact).

Answer (score 3):

No, consider $f(x) = x\sin(\frac 1x)$ with $f(0) = 0$ on $[0,1]$.

Comment: Do you mean $f(x)=x \sin(\frac{1}{x})$  for $(0,1]$ , $f(x)=0$ for $x=0$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ but not point-wise continuous?

Comment: @gbd Is it possible for a function $f\colon [0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ to be continuous but not uniformly continuous?

Comment: @ClementC., Yes.

Comment: @gbd [Are you sure?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heine%E2%80%93Cantor_theorem) (You may want to fully internalize the notions of continuity and uniform continuity, and the relevant theorems that pertain to these two concepts, before going to more refined notions such as absolute continuity).

Comment: @ClementC., $f(x) = x\sin(\frac 1x)$ with $f(0) = 0$ on $[0,1]$ is continuous for $x\in [0,1]$ and therefore its uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ but not absolutely continuous. Is that right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. ${}{}$